# ios generate application specific key

Tags: ios, security, encryption

I'm working on an ios application without authentication. Now I would like to protect my server API from calls other then my ios application. A possible solution would be to have the application generate a unique key (based on the appname and the signing), which is not stored on the device since this is the main problem. I could think off an application logic that does some protection combined with some file encryption but the problem is that somewhere something is stored (ex public key can be stored in keychain but still not safe for my API-hackers).

Anyone any tips/advice on how I can handle this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no 100% secure way to make sure that the request comes from your application, if the key is available to the iPhone, it's available to extract from the iPhone.

You can make it reasonably safe by calculating a key runtime from info in the application as you say and communicate it over SSL, but a determined attacker can always reverse engineer the key generation too.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what do you mean by calculating a key runtime from info in the application? Do you mean like a timestamp/ some code logic stuff? As you stated before I fear there is no 100% secure way to do this :( :(

Comment: I mean as in either having the key encrypted in the application or calculating it runtime from some static data, just to make it a bit harder to recover by just opening the binary in a hex editor. Also called security by obscurity, but really the best you can do in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is employ mutually-authenticated SSL, so that your server will only accept incoming connections from your app and your app will only communicate with your server.

Here's the high-level approach. Create a self-signed server SSL certificate and deploy on your web server. You can use freely available tools for this, like keytool, and I think (but don't know for sure) that Apple includes a tool for this with the iOS SDK. Then create a self-signed client and deploy that within your application in a custom keystore included in your application as a resource. Configure the server to require client-side SSL authentication and to only accept the client certificate you generated. Configure the client to use that client-side certificate to identify itself and only accept the one server-side certificate you installed on your server for that part of it.

If someone/something other than your app attempts to connect to your server, the SSL connection will not be created, as the server will reject incoming SSL connections that do not present the client certificate that you have included in your app.